# Приоритет логических операторов

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if not b and a < sys.float_info.epsilon:
      (                 h               )
      (   t    )
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, как работает этот синтаксис:

- К чему относится not?
- К выражению h, t, или к переменной b?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence - прочитайте, станет понятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в таких случаях может помочь модуль [dis (`Disassembler for Python bytecode`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html):

```
import dis

In [16]: dis.dis("not b and a < sys.float_info.epsilon")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 UNARY_NOT                                  # применяем NOT к `b`
              4 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    16                 # если условие ложно перейти к шагу 16
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              8 LOAD_NAME                2 (sys)
             10 LOAD_ATTR                3 (float_info)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                4 (epsilon)
             14 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)             # сравниваем `a < sys.float_info.epsilon`
        >>   16 RETURN_VALUE                               # возвращаем результат
                                                           #   (в нашем случае результат сравнения `a < sys.float_info.epsilon`)
```

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Выражение в вопросе эквивалентно

```
if (not b) and (a < sys.float_info.epsilon):
    ...
```